# Some questions on definition of Grassman manifolds

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

In W.M. Boothby, [An introduction to differentiable manifolds and Riemannian geometry , Page 64.](http://books.google.com/books?id=oWLJ6zaSwyIC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) We use coordinate correspondences $\phi_j : U_j \to R^{k(n-k)}$ in order to define *Grassman manifolds* where $U_j'$s are open sets in $F(k, n)$. I can't see :

1. Why the map $\phi_j$ are properly defined?
2. Why each $\phi_j$ maps $U_j$ onto $R^{k(n-k)}$ homeomorphicaly?

It is mentioned in the book that verification of these questions for Grassman manifold $G(2,4)$, the 2-planes through the origin of $R^4$, is sufficient to show how proceed in general. Could someone guide me how could I prove  the above questions for the case $G(2,4)$? and how can we switch to the general case? Is there any reference include a complete proof of the above questions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What exactly is $U_j$?

Comment: we first define equivalence relation ~ on the set of k-frames, say $F(k, n)$, as follow : X~Y iff there is a $A$ in $GL(k, R)$ such that $X=AY$. For any k-tuples J=(k_1,...,k_k) the matrices whose $k_j$'s columns are equal form an open set in $F(k,n)$ called $V_J$. Now if $\pi$ : F(k,n) \to F(k,n)/$~$  be projection map we define $U_J= \pi(V_J)$ as a open set in F(k,n)/~.